# How to auto authenticate openfire meetings?

Tags: authentication, openfire, jitsi

I am using Openfire Meetings plugin, and the video call opens up from my webapp when the user clicks a link. On clicking the link Jitsi again asks for username and password. I want to automatically authenticate the users as they are already logged in to the webapp.
I have the credentials but can't find a way to auto authenticate Jitsi.

I have tried:

1) Anonymous login: Not desirable, because then anyone who is not a part of our app can use the service.

2) Sending keys in the url.

3) Using jwt: Didn't work but I'd like some help on this.

4) Debugging the source code on Chrome, code is complex so couldn't find much.